# Stacked bar chart is created even though aggregation function is non-summative

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I have a concatenated graph which features a main line graph which has a brush selection tool allowing the user to pan across the lines and points and change the data on 4 other graphs. For one of the other graphs, I have attempted to take the average of line graph data but it doesn't work. Instead of giving me a singular bar, I get stacked bars and the error: "Stacking is applied even though the aggregate function is non-summative ("mean")".

Here is my code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "title": "This is kinda sick yo",
  "data": {
    "url": "data/test3.csv"
  },
  "hconcat": [
    {
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "condition": {
            "selection": "brush",
            "title": "Species",
            "field": "Species",
            "type": "nominal",
            "scale": {"range": ["green", "#FFFF00", "red"]}
          },
          "value": "lightgray"
        },
        "x": {
          "field": "Variable",
          "type": "nominal",
          "axis": {"labelAngle": -45, "title": "Element",
        "grid": false}
        },
        "y": {
          "title": "Total",
          "field": "Total",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
          "tooltip": [
      {"field": "Variable", "type": "nominal"},
      {"field": "Total", "type": "quantitative"},
    ]
      },
      "width": 550,
      "height": 300,
      "mark": {"type": "line", "point": "true"},
      "selection": {"brush": {"encodings": ["x"], "type": "interval"}},
      "transform": [{"filter": {"selection": "click"}}]
    },
      {
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "condition": {
            "selection": "click",
            "field": "Total",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "scale": {"range": ["green", "#FFFF00", "red"]}
          },
          "value": "lightgray"
        },
        "y": {"field": "Total", "aggregate": "average"},
        "x": {"title": "Species", "field": "Species", "type": "nominal"},
          "tooltip": [
      {"field": "Species", "type": "nominal"},
      {"field": "Total", "type": "quantitative", "aggregate": "average"},
      {"field": "Variable", "type": "nominal"}
    ]
      },
      "height": 300,
      "width": 80,
      "mark": "bar",
      "selection": {"click": {"encodings": ["color"], "type": "multi"}},
      "transform": [{"filter": {"selection": "brush"}}, ]
    },
    {
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "condition": {
            "selection": "click",
            "field": "Sex",
            "type": "nominal",
            "scale": {"range": ["#993162", "#75b0a2", "grey"]},
            "legend": null
          },
          "value": "lightgray"
        },
        "y": {"field": "Fisher Sex Value", "type": "quantitative", "aggregate": "mean"},
        "x": {"title": "Sex", "field": "Sex", "type": "nominal"},
          "tooltip": [
      {"field": "Sex", "type": "nominal"},
      {"field": "Fisher Sex Value", "type": "quantitative", "aggregate": "mean"},
    ]
      },
      "height": 300,
      "width": 75,
      "mark": "bar",
      "selection": {"click": {"encodings": ["color"], "type": "multi"}},
      "transform": [{"filter": {"selection": "brush"}}]
    },
      {
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "condition": {
            "selection": "click",
            "field": "Sex",
            "type": "nominal",
            "scale": {"range": ["#993162", "#75b0a2", "grey"]},
            "legend": null
          },
          "value": "lightgray"
        },
        "y": {"field": "Mink Sex Value", "type": "quantitative", "aggregate": "mean"},
        "x": {"title": "Sex", "field": "Sex", "type": "nominal"},
          "tooltip": [
      {"field": "Sex", "type": "nominal"},
      {"field": "Mink Sex Value", "type": "quantitative", "aggregate": "mean"},
    ]
      },
      "height": 300,
      "width": 75,
      "mark": "bar",
      "selection": {"click": {"encodings": ["color"], "type": "multi"}},
      "transform": [{"filter": {"selection": "brush"}}]
    },
      {
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "condition": {
            "selection": "click",
            "field": "Sex",
            "type": "nominal",
            "scale": {"range": ["#993162", "#75b0a2", "grey"]}
          },
          "value": "lightgray"
        },
        "y": {"field": "Otter Sex Value", "type": "quantitative", "aggregate": "mean"},
        "x": {"title": "Sex", "field": "Sex", "type": "nominal"},
          "tooltip": [
      {"field": "Sex", "type": "nominal"},
      {"field": "Otter Sex Value", "type": "quantitative", "aggregate": "mean"},
    ]
      },
      "height": 300,
      "width": 75,
      "mark": "bar",
      "selection": {"click": {"encodings": ["color"], "type": "multi"}},
      "transform": [{"filter": {"selection": "brush"}}]
    }
  ]
}
```

The first graph is the line graph and the second graph is the one where aggregation fails and I get stacks.[Here is an image of what the graph looks like currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRXDg.png). Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vega-Lite's encoding aggregations will implicitly group by unaggregated fields you specify in a set of encodings. A simplified version of the second chart's encoding looks like this:

```
{
  "encoding": {
  "color": {"field": "Total"},
  "y": {"field": "Total", "aggregate": "average"},
  "x": {"field": "Species"},
  "tooltip": [
    {"field": "Species"},
    {"field": "Total", "aggregate": "average"},
    {"field": "Variable"}
  ]
```

The unaggregated encodings are `["Total", "Species", "Variable"]`, so the operation will group-by these before computing the `average` of `Total` within each group. Grouping by unique values of `Total` before taking the mean of `Total` in each group is probably not what you were hoping for.

Perhaps removing the color encoding from that chart will give you more meaningful results.

Comment: When I remove the color encoding, it breaks the entire graph (colors are all messed up) and gives me an error citing "Conflicting scale property "range"", for the 4 other graphs (first line graph, and the 3 bar graphs after the bar graph without the color encoding. How can I fix this?

Comment: You'll likely need to specify [independent color scale resolution](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/resolve.html) if you want each chart to have different scales. I'm unable to check if this works because you did not include the full code & data required to reproduce your chart.